# JPA iteration over a collection field

Tags: jpa, collections, iteration

Let's say there is a entity class like this

```
@Entity
public class User {
...
public Collection<User> followers;
...
}
```

Lets say user has thousands of user followers. I wanna paginate... Do I have to get my hands into JPQL to paginate the result without any other choice?

```
int page = 5;
User u = em.find(User.class, id);

for (User u : u.getFollowers(page, 100)) { // get the 5th 100 result
// do some stuff
}
```

is there any similar solution or a pattern out there? is it possible to paginate field of a collection runtime by just accessing a field `u.getFollowers(page, 100)` without the code below?

I know this one already...

```
int page = 5;
List<User> followers = em.createQuery("select u.followers from User u where u.id=?1", User.class)
.setParameter(1, id).setFirstResult(page*100).setMaxResult(100).getResultList();
```

Comment: you answered your own question :) Using JPA queries is the answer

Comment: then i failed to question what i was hoping for... gonna edit more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which JPA implementation are you using? 
if you are using hibernate you can take advantage of some of hibernates features.

as stated in the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization)

The `createFilter()` method can be used to efficiently retrieve subsets of a collection without needing to initialize the whole collection.

```
 List<User> followerPage = session.createFilter( followers, "")
                                  .setFirstResult(500).setMaxResults(100)
                                  .list();
```

You can use `createFilter()` to get the size of a collection without initializing it, also important for pagination.

```
 ( (Integer) session.createFilter( followers, "select count(*)" ).list().get(0) ).intValue()
```

Comment: i am not using hibernate but thanks to your answer that's exactly what i was looking for. is something similar for EclipseLink?

Comment: @HayatiGuvence : yes, YOU gave the solution, as many of us stated in our answers, but you haven't trusted us. With EclipseLink, as well as for other compliant JPAs, the LIMIT statement is inserted by the API behind the scenes. Haven't you looked at the API log?

Comment: @perissf : i asked for a pattern not to create a solution. before i got this solution i had to write my own generic CriteriaBuilder for paginating any collection without the JPQL. This answer is the simplest, best and the cleanest comparing any others. If i had this answer earlier... I never have known the existence of a provider level solution. Your answer is as awesome as others. this one is what i was looking for. I deeply appreciate your time and concerns for others!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to execute a query to be able to paginate.

The snippet in the last example is fine, except paginating without using any order to sort the results of the query is not a good idea: there is no guarantee on the deterministic order of the results in you don't use any `order by` clause, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

> Do I have to get my hands into JPQL to paginate the result without any
>   other choice?

It would depend on how you would like to use the retrieved data. basically it would be best if the pagination is done in the query to get the exact rows that you need rather than getting all the available rows then manually doing a sublist.

> is there any similar solution or a pattern out there? is it possible
>   to paginate field of a collection runtime by just accessing a field
>   u.getFollowers(page, 100) without the code below

if you want to do the pagination after retrieving all the "followers" then simply use the ArrayList constructor which takes a collection as a param then get the sublist.

Comment: It is possible. Not efficient to get all the rows and extract a sublist of that.

Answer (score 1):

The JPQL Query you have posted has the only problem of not having specified an ORDER BY statement. It is important to use an ORDER BY, as multiple queries will be used for each page, and you want to ensure you get back the results in the same order.

Concerning your comment about the supposed inefficiency in getting all the rows and then extracting a sublist of that: well, the JPA provider will build behind the scenes a complete query, including the LIMIT statement, when the JDBC connector supports it. So, you don't have to care about it.

If you want to make sure about what query is effectively sent to the JDBC connector, then set the JPA provider's logging level to FINE and check it out.

For further reference, if you are using EclipseLink provider, have a look at this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Pagination).

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options:

1. Use a JPA `Query` with `setFirstResult()/setMaxResult()`
2. Fetch the `List` and take out the `subList` you need.

**Option 1 is the most compatible, clean and recommended solution.**

**Option 2 may be a performance (and even a memory) problem - or not.** 
This depends on how much rows may be read in the worst case and what ratio of rows are read typically. **If the number of rows is small or you read the whole list in most situations anyway - then go for it.**
There *might* also be some JPA implementation out there which really fetches only the requested records of a list lazily in some cases, but be careful and have a detailed look on the documentation of your JPA implementation. (But I am not aware of such implementations)

Answer (score 0):

There is one approach or pattern if you want to call it that way, described in Adam Bien's book [Real World Java EE Patterns Rethinking Best Practices](http://www.amazon.de/Real-World-Patterns-Rethinking-Practices/dp/0557078326/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327873771&sr=8-1), called Paginator.

One implementation strategy is based on a JPA query, using the already mentioned Query approach (first and max result). The following example is out of the book page 125:

```
@Stateful
public class CustomerQueryBean implements Iterator<List<Customer>> {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
private int index = 0;
private int pageSize = 10;
private boolean next = true;

public void setPageSize(int pageSize){
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
}

public List<Customer> next(){
    List<Customer> retVal = null;
    Query query = this.em.createNamedQuery(Customer.ALL);
    query.setFirstResult(getFirst());
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    retVal = query.getResultList();

    if(retVal.size()==0){
        this.next = false;
    }
    index++;
    return retVal;
}
private int getFirst(){
    return index * pageSize;
}
public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.next;
}
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Operation remove …");
}
@Remove
public void close(){
    this.em.clear();
    this.em.close();
}
}
```

As you can see, the approach is based on the Iterator interface. The reason for that is that the client is just interested in the iteration logic anyway. After executing the next() method you retrieve a new subset of entities.

Hope that helps to bring some structure into your pagination logic.